# Why the new assets don't load from the resources folder?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have this script which is supposed to assemble a character on a prefab using sprite sheets, but nothing happens when I run the script. I think it might not be finding the files because Debug.Log does not give me any of the sprite's names. But the file path is definitely correct so perhaps its not finding the game objects on the the prefabs hierarchy.

```
public class Character : MonoBehaviour
{

IEnumerator Start()
{
    yield return PullAssets();
}

IEnumerator PullAssets()
{
    Sprite[] amazon_armor = Resources.LoadAll<Sprite>("New Art/amazon/revisions/armor.png");
    Sprite amazon_armor1 = amazon_armor[0];
    Sprite amazon_armor2 = amazon_armor[1];
    Sprite amazon_armor3 = amazon_armor[2];
    
    Sprite[] amazon_body = Resources.LoadAll<Sprite>("New Art/amazon/revisions/body.png");
    Sprite amazon_body1 = amazon_body[0];
    Sprite amazon_body2 = amazon_body[1];
    Sprite amazon_body3 = amazon_body[2];
    Sprite amazon_body4 = amazon_body[3];

    Sprite amazon_body5 = amazon_body[4];
    Sprite amazon_body6 = amazon_body[5];
    Sprite amazon_body7 = amazon_body[6];
    Sprite amazon_body8 = amazon_body[7];
    Sprite amazon_body9 = amazon_body[8];
    Sprite amazon_body10 = amazon_body[9];
    Sprite amazon_body11 = amazon_body[10];
    Sprite amazon_body12 = amazon_body[11];
    Sprite amazon_body13 = amazon_body[12];
    Sprite amazon_body14 = amazon_body[13];
    Sprite amazon_body15 = amazon_body[14];
    Sprite amazon_body16 = amazon_body[15];

    Sprite amazon_body17 = amazon_body[16];
    Sprite amazon_body18 = amazon_body[17];
    Sprite amazon_body19 = amazon_body[18];
    Sprite amazon_body20 = amazon_body[19];

    Sprite[] amazon_bow = Resources.LoadAll<Sprite>("New Art/amazon/revisions/bow.png");
    Sprite amazon_bow1 = amazon_bow[0];
    Sprite amazon_bow2 = amazon_bow[1];

    Sprite amazon_brow = Resources.Load<Sprite>("New Art/amazon/revisions/brow.png");

    Sprite amazon_cape = Resources.Load<Sprite>("New Art/amazon/revisions/cape.png");

    Sprite[] amazon_hair = Resources.LoadAll<Sprite>("New Art/amazon/revisions/hair.png");
    Sprite amazon_hair1 = amazon_hair[0];
    Sprite amazon_hair2 = amazon_hair[1];

    Sprite amazon_nose = Resources.Load<Sprite>("New Art/amazon/revisions/nose.png");

    Sprite[] amazon_shoes = Resources.LoadAll<Sprite>("New Art/amazon/revisions/shoes.png");
    Sprite amazon_shoes1 = amazon_shoes[0];
    Sprite amazon_shoes2 = amazon_shoes[1];
    Sprite amazon_shoes3 = amazon_shoes[2];

    Sprite amazon_skirt = Resources.Load<Sprite>("New Art/amazon/revisions/skirt.png");

    Sprite amazon_sword = Resources.Load<Sprite>("New Art/amazon/revisions/sword.png");

    //hip
    GameObject Hip = GameObject.Find("Hip");
    Hip.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = amazon_body15;
    
    //torso
    GameObject Torso = GameObject.Find("Body");
    Torso.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = amazon_body7;

    //torso armor
    GameObject ArmorBody = gameObject.transform.Find("Root/Pos_Hip/Bone_Hip/Pos_Body/Bone_Body/Body/Armor Body").gameObject;
    ArmorBody.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = amazon_armor1;

    //neck
    GameObject Neck = GameObject.Find("Neck");
    Neck.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = amazon_body4;

    //neck armor
    GameObject ArmorNeck = GameObject.Find("Armor Neck");
    ArmorNeck.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = amazon_armor2;

    //head
    GameObject Head = GameObject.Find("Head");
    Head.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = amazon_body1;

    //nose
    GameObject Nose = GameObject.Find("Nose");
    Nose.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = amazon_nose;

    //eyebrow
    GameObject Eyebrow = GameObject.Find("Eyebrow");
    Eyebrow.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = amazon_brow;

    //hair bottom
    GameObject HairBot = GameObject.Find("Hair B");
    HairBot.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = amazon_hair2;

    //hair
    GameObject Hair = GameObject.Find("Hair F");
    Hair.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = amazon_hair1;

    //left upper arm
    GameObject LUArm = GameObject.Find("Upper Arm L");
    LUArm.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = amazon_body3;

    //left lower arm
    GameObject LLArm = GameObject.Find("Lower Arm L");
    LLArm.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = amazon_body5;

    //left hand
    GameObject LHand = GameObject.Find("Hand L 0");
    LHand.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = amazon_body14;

    //right upper arm
    GameObject RUArm = GameObject.Find("Upper Arm R");
    RUArm.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = amazon_body2;

    GameObject RUArmArmor = GameObject.Find("Armor Upper Arm R");
    RUArmArmor.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = amazon_armor3;

    //right lower arm
    GameObject RLArm = GameObject.Find("Lower Arm R");
    RLArm.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = amazon_body9;

    //right hand
    GameObject RHand = GameObject.Find("Hand R 0");
    RHand.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = amazon_body13;

    //left upper leg
    GameObject LULeg = GameObject.Find("Upper Leg L");
    LULeg.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = amazon_body6;

    //left lower leg
    GameObject LLLeg = GameObject.Find("Lower Leg L");
    LLLeg.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = amazon_body12;

    //left foot
    GameObject LFoot = GameObject.Find("Foot L");
    LFoot.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = amazon_body18;

    //left boot
    GameObject LBoot = GameObject.Find("Boots Foot L");
    LBoot.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = amazon_shoes1;

    //right upper leg
    GameObject RULeg = GameObject.Find("Upper Leg R");
    RULeg.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = amazon_body5;

    //right lower leg
    GameObject RLLeg = GameObject.Find("Lower Leg F");
    RLLeg.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = amazon_body10;

    //right foot
    GameObject RFoot = GameObject.Find("Foot R");
    RFoot.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = amazon_body17;

    //right boot
    GameObject RBoot = GameObject.Find("Boots Foot F");
    RBoot.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = amazon_shoes3;

    //right hand weapon
    GameObject RHWeapon = GameObject.Find("Weapon R");
    RHWeapon.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = amazon_sword;

    yield return null;
}
}
```

Comment: It could be [`this issue`](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/118829/unity3d-resources-loadallsprite-empty-array). Try re-importing assets or closing and opening Unity.

Comment: You have some reason why you dont set it in inspector?Since all your items are int this folder "New Art/amazon/revisions" good idea will be to declare some string variable so you will only change your "head" "shoes" "body" etc. + Check this post about GameObject.Find before your PC burn :)) https://answers.unity.com/questions/1170097/which-is-more-efficient-gameobjectfind-or-public-g.html

Comment: I'm trying to do it for a big number of prefabs

Comment: @TEEBQNE thanks I tried both, it didn't work

Answer (score 1):

This seemed to work

```
Sprite[] amazon_armor = Resources.LoadAll<Sprite>("New Art/amazon/revisions/armor") as Sprite[];
    Sprite amazon_armor1 = amazon_armor[0];
    GameObject ArmorBody = transform.Find("Root/Pos_Hip/Bone_Hip/Pos_Body/Bone_Body/Body/Armor Body").gameObject;
    ArmorBody.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = amazon_armor1;
```